# Como manter o App sempre logado com o Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Como fazer com que meu App inicie logado após ser encerado?

Ex: Loguei uma vez e toda vez que eu iniciar o aplicativo novamente ele já inicie logado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação [Gerenciar usuários no Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users), a maneira recomendada de identificar o usuário conectado é chamar o método `getCurrentUser()`. Se nenhum usuário estiver conectado, `getCurrentUser()` retorna um valor nulo.

Exemplo:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Usuário está logado
} else {
    // usuário não está logado
}
```